# Adding 2 vectors and keeping the resulting magnitude below a max value

Tags: vectors

I have 2 vectors, $\vec{A}=(x, y)$ and $\vec{B}=(u, v)$. I also have a max value $M$. I want to add the vectors together so that the resulting magnitude is no greater than $M$, by multiplying $\vec{B}$ by a certain factor $f$.

Specifically, I am looking for the largest possible $f$ such that $\| \vec{A} + f\vec{B} \| \leq M$.

Please note that in my situation, $\| \vec{A} \| \leq M$, which means $0 \leq f$. I also want $f\leq1$, because in my situation it doesn't make sense to multiply $\vec{B}$ by a factor greater than 1.

To find $f$, I proceed as follows. In the case where $\| \vec{A} + \vec{B} \| \leq M$, I can take $f=1$ and be done. If that's not the case, then I can use the definition of vector magnitude and solve the following equation for $f$:
$$
M=\sqrt{(x+fu)^2+(y+fv)^2}
$$

Using WolframAlpha, I get the following 2 solutions:
$$
f=\frac{\pm\sqrt{(2ux+2vy)^2-4(u^2+v^2)(-M^2+x^2+y^2)} -2ux-2vy}{2(u^2+v^2)}
$$

This is a somewhat involved equation. My question is: is there an easier / simpler way to find $f$? This is for physics implementation in a game and any optimization helps with performance, as in my case this needs to be calculated several times per frame.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is how you want to fix the issue? If you multiply the vector $B$ by your parameter $f$, you are *changing the direction of* the resultant $A+B$. Wouldn't it be easier (and maybe make more sense in your game) to calculate the resultant $A+B$ and if its magnitude is greater than $M$, reduce its length by some factor, preserving the direction? Maybe you don't care about the direction, in which case ignore this comment - it was just the first thought that came to mind.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware and it's what I want :) Previously, I was doing what you suggest (add $A+B$, if magnitude is greater than $M$ then normalize and multiply by $M$), but the problem is I need $A$ to be taken **as is**. By playing with the resulting vector, I am indirectly changing my original $A$. As an example, if $A=(10,0)$, $B=(0,100)$ and $M=20$, I need my resulting vector to have 10 as its first dimension. Using that approach, I get $(1.99, 19.9)$, which means I've lost 8.01 units that my $A$ had. I hope this makes sense and I'm not being confusing...

Comment: No, it makes perfect sense. In that case I'm of little help, but I don't think you can optimize the equation. What might be faster from a run-time perspective is to generate some vector with values of $f$ (from 0 to 1 in increments of 0.01, or something), and test them in some order until you get as close as possible to a length $M$. Depending on how cleverly you test the values of $f$, this could be faster than brute-force solving the equation.

Comment: Yes, I had briefly considered doing a binary search on the value of $f$ until I get within an acceptable distance of $M$... Maybe it's worth doing some benchmarks to see if it's much faster!

On the other hand I was hoping there was maybe a more clever approach using some properties of linear combination or something... It's been a while since I've done all this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use $t$ instead of $f$.

The points $A + tB$ lie on a line through the point $A$ in the direction of the vector $B$. You are trying to find the values of $t$ that give you the intersections of this line with a circle $C$ of radius $M$ centered at the origin.

If the point $A$ lies inside the circle $C$, there will be two values of $t$, one negative and one positive. If the point $A+B$ lies outside the circle $C$, then the positive $t$ value will be less than $1$.

So how to find the desired value of $t$.

We have:

\begin{align}
&A + tB \;\text{  lies on the circle  } C  \\
\Leftrightarrow\;& \|A + tB\| = M          \\
\Leftrightarrow\;& \|A + tB\|^2 = M^2      \\
\Leftrightarrow\;& (A + tB) \cdot (A + tB) = M^2  \\
\Leftrightarrow\;& A \cdot A + 2t(A \cdot B) + t^2(B.\cdot B) = M^2  
\end{align}
The desired solution of the quadratic is:
$$
t = \frac{-A \cdot B + \sqrt{ (A \cdot B)^2 - (B.B) (A \cdot A - M^2)}  } {  B \cdot B}
$$

The necessary code would be:

```
double AA = x*x + y*y;     // A dot A
double BB = u*u + v*v;     // B dot B
double AB = u*x + v*y;     // A dot B

double d = sqrt(AB*AB - BB*(AA - M*M));

double t = (d - AB)/BB;
```

This is roughly the same formula you derived, but in a rather tidier form (in my opinion), and with slightly less arithmetic. I don't think you can do any better than this. The only part that will take any time is the square root, and I think this is unavoidable. You should be able to do this calculation millions of times a second, even on a wristwatch. Iterative algorithms will be much slower, as you already discovered.

Comment: I agree that this form is a bit easier to read / understand. However, I notice that in my case, I have a coefficient of 2 multiplying both $A \cdot B$ terms and the denominator $B \cdot B$, and the $B \cdot B$ in the radicand is multiplied by 4. Is there a reason your form of the solution does not have that?

Comment: The 2's and 4's all cancel. Five minutes coding will tell you whether my formula and yours give the same answer. If they don't, ping me back and I'll see if I made an algebra error.

Comment: They indeed cancel out. Just because you made me realize that, I'll give you the answer even if our equations are the same :)

Answer (score 0):

Iterative approximation to the required value of $f$ seems to fit to your needs, if I understood well.
You want$$
\left( {x + f\,u} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {y + f\,v} \right)^{\,2}  - M^{\,2}  \le 0
$$
i.e.
$$
\,f^{\,2}  + 2\,{{\left( {x\,u\, + \,y\,v} \right)} \over {\left( {u^{\,2}  + \,v^{\,2} } \right)}}\,f + {{x^{\,2}  + y^{\,2}  - M^{\,2} } \over {\left( {u^{\,2}  + \,v^{\,2} } \right)}} \le 0
$$
where the left term is a vertical parabola, with axis at $
f =  - \,{{\left( {x\,u\, + \,y\,v} \right)} \over {\left( {u^{\,2}  + \,v^{\,2} } \right)}}
$ , etc.
Now fix $f=1$ and calculate the ordinate: if negative that is ok, if positive apply the Newton-Raphson iteration and in a few steps you will get a good approximation of the required value for $f$.
Adjust the algorithm to fix for precision / max no. of steps, banal values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I tried playing with iterative approximation approaches (like G Cab mentioned) and doing a binary search to find a suitable value of $f$, but nothing could come close to the performance of simply calculating the equation directly.

I made sure to use any possible optimization (storing all intermediate steps of the calculation to reuse as much as possible, using multiplication rather than power to calculate the squares, etc).

So, unless there is an approach that doesn't involve the definition of vector magnitude, I don't think there's a better way to calculate $f$.